# How can I aggregate by custom areas?

Tags: pandas, shapely, geopandas

I have a geojson file which defines areas (as polygons). When I load it as `df_areas` with `geopandas` it looks like this:

```
                                        id                                           geometry
0     a9d04068-7220-433d-bbcf-50c51c1ee243  POLYGON ((13.43715051671244 52.48283068240888,...
1     9fd4ec97-db2c-4a40-b0ff-b54976bf4784  POLYGON ((13.4383267580672 52.4822756653842, 1...
2     43c2ad0a-51c0-45ff-aab3-51dbfb1119e9  POLYGON ((13.44054177168731 52.48185471774156,...
3     5cd2aa14-5265-432b-a13e-aa99d1fb94ca  POLYGON ((13.43429163342489 52.48417966481776,...
4     1e6c7de6-aa7d-4828-97d8-393738fd6df4  POLYGON ((13.43611174444709 52.48332083376235,...
5     409982b2-d638-4682-b9d1-76e2a9786103  POLYGON ((13.4383267580672 52.48283068240888, ...
```

Then I have a `df_data` which has a column `geometry` with `shapely.geometry.Point` as values. I want to get a heat map, where each cell is one of the areas defined in `df_areas` and the value is the count of Points from `df_data.geometry` that were in this area.

How can I do that?

Comment: you could use the [rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) package in order to build a spatial index from `df_areas`. `rtree` then allows for each point to find efficiently the candidate areas which might contain it so that you can test them explicitly and if a match is found, increment the counter...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use [`geopandas.sjoin`](http://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html#spatial-joins).

Requirements:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libspatialindex-dev
$ pip3 install rtree --user
```

To get the joined dataset:

```
# gdf contains Points in the 'geometry' column
# world contains Polygons in the 'geometry' column
df_joined = gpd.sjoin(gdf, world, op='within')
```